# Passing credentials to access share-point through SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I have created an SSIS project where source is an excel file on sharepoint location. I am getting error "Failed Validation".

I think i should pass username/password to access the sharepoint location? How can I do that in SSIS?

I tried adding "Add service reference". But  when I right click the project name in the solution explorer, the "Add service reference" option is missing. I am using Visual studio 2015, .Net 4.5.2 framework.

Please suggest how can I access share-point through SSIS by passing credentials.

Comment: Sharepoint Online? What version of SQL Server is it?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server 2016